# Loading the next scene in unity after the player collides with the button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Roll-a-Ball game in Unity but I am stuck at the loading part. I want the next level to load when the player touches the button but my code doesn't seem to work. Please help.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player") {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1); //1 is the build index of the scene
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define exactly what `doesn't seem to work` means

Comment: My player touches the button (collides with it ) and the scene does not load . Unity doesn't show errors too.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Is your method even entered? Is your if condition true? Is your "Button" an actual 2D UI.Button or a 3D object with collider? Do you have a Rigidbody component? How do you move the Player?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add colliders to both object
Add layers to both objects
In project Settings/Physics 2D check layers for this to objcts to match
Remove on trigger in colliders for Both objets
Add RigidBody2D to both objects
OFc 2D is if it is 2D game